# Display image stored as blob in Razor (MVC)

Tags: ms-access, razor, model-view-controller

I'm devoloping a website which is integrated with another system around the organization.
One of them is a microsoft access program that is storing the images in varbinary data type at mssql..

trying to display those images in my website cause broken images and it won't work, when ever I store my own images (sent from my website) it's working fine (converting it to base64 and so).

My guess is that the ms program is storing the images as adodb stream (blob).

How can I display those images? they are extremely important

Comment: You guess Access is storing them a certain way? Please make sure of it. Access can store images as a variety of OLE object types, such as  binary data (a true BLOB), package (a file container, similar to zip), bitmap image, etc.. Images with different OLE object types can be stored in one container. You need to account for this type when displaying the image (and using anything but binary data will likely cause this problem).

Comment: The guy who did it is unreachable, the image is stored in varbinary in the sql, for example "0x151C26000000200000008000B0014000...."  it's a very long data.. And this is coming from the program he did..

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. You can create a linked table in Access, and try to determine the OLE object type from there. Lebans's [OleToDisk](http://www.lebans.com/oletodisk.htm) is a useful reference.

Comment: It's adodb stream

Comment: That's not an OLE object type...

Comment: Looking at the code looks like it's AdtypeBinary, is there such thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164624/discussion-between-elkayam-gabay-and-erik-von-asmuth).